# Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, session-fixation

I have research in SE about this issues and not found the answer to resolve the problem occur.

From my problem of view, every time I **logout the session in web and open the new tab**, this error always trigger . I think the session management not allow the csrf token to be exposed in another tab in browser.

When I trace the JSESSIONID in chrome cookies console,it shows that no response given compared to normal successful login which give response of JSESSIONID.

This is my login page form:

```
<form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/login' />" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <div id="username_input">
            <div id="username_inputleft"></div>
            <div id="username_inputmiddle">                 
                <input type="text" name="username" id="url" placeholder="<spring:message code="login.name" />" >
                <img id="url_user" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/login/mailicon.png"/>" alt="">              
            </div>
            <div id="username_inputright"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="password_input">
            <div id="password_inputleft"></div>
            <div id="password_inputmiddle">                 
                <input type="password" name="password" id="url" placeholder="<spring:message code="login.password" />" >
                <img id="url_password" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/login/passicon.png"/>" alt="">              
            </div>
            <div id="password_inputright"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="submit">               
            <input type="image" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/login/submit_hover.png"/>" id="submit1"  value="Sign In" />                
            <input type="image" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/login/submit.png"/>" id="submit2"  value="Sign In"/>               
        </div>          
        </form>
```

I think the problem was from session management in my security configuration here:

```
.sessionManagement()
        .sessionFixation()
        .newSession()
        .maximumSessions( 1 );
```

but somehow I cannot solve the problem. I hope someone can help.

Update:

I logout by using this link:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/logout" />">
 <spring:url value="/resources/images/logout.jpg" var="logoutimg" />
 <img src="${logoutimg}">
 <spring:url value="/resources/images/logout_txt.jpg" var="logouttxtimg" />
 <img class="hidden-xs" src="${logouttxtimg}" />
</a>
```

Comment: Another tab isn't a new session it is the same session. Also HOW are you doing the logout? Show the link/form you are using.

Comment: I think new tab also dont affect session, but it does'nt work only when i open same link in new tab, it work normally on same tab

Comment: You will need a new browser else everything will be shared. So you need to use Chrome and Firefox for instance (or shutdown chrome first). Opening a new tab, or clicking a link is the same it isn't a new browser.

Comment: When using CSFR you cannot logout using a link, you will need a form posting to the logout link to include the CSFR token.

Comment: Yup, open in new browser,or restart the current browser also work as normal, so does it mean I cannot use 2 tab with same URL and always need to restart or open new browser to make it work?

Comment: You cannot have 2 different sessions in 2 browser tabs as that isn't how browsers work.

Comment: can you give me some example to properly logout by using CSFR?

Comment: That is simply explained in the spring security reference guide.

Comment: Ok,thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, we need to use the /logout or /j_spring_security_logout to log the current user out. If we use another method to logout programmatically, the logout process will not complete unless I using the url provided. Thanks for help. If someone come out with the solution to logout programmtically completely without affecting the spring security, please tell me then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
@RequestMapping("/Logout")
public ModelAndView processLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("Login");
    return mv;
}
```

And in your login page insert

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                    value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Don't forget to add this to your security configuration

```
<security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        logout-success-url='/login?logout' logout-url="/Logout"
        invalidate-session="true" />
```